# rvest html() not recognizing URLs

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

So I'm writing a web scraper with R to search zillow for the median house value in each county in WA state. I'm using the rvest package, and here is the code in question:

```
URL <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_counties_in_Washington"
wiki <- html(URL)

#Getting the list of counties in WA
counties <- wiki %>%
  html_nodes(".wikitable td:nth-child(1) a") %>%
  html_text()

#Putting together a list to pull my search terms from
searchTerms <- list()

for(i in 1:length(counties)) {
  searchTerms[[i]] <- paste0(counties[i], ", WA", sep="")
}
searchTerms <- gsub(",", "", searchTerms)
searchTerms <- gsub(" ", "-", searchTerms)

homeValues <- list()

#Getting the HTML for each county using the search terms in the URL,
#eventually it will pull the homeValues data from that HTML.
for(j in 1:length(searchTerms)){
  zillowURL <- paste0("www.zillow.com/", searchTerms[j], "/home-values/", sep="")
  zillowHTML <- html(zillowURL)

}
```

I'm not finished yet, of course, but when I run this code, I get the error message

> "Error: File [www.zillow.com/Adams-County-WA/home-values/](http://www.zillow.com/Adams-County-WA/home-values/) does not
>   exist"

, with Adams County, WA being the first alphabetical county in WA state. My guess is that this has something to do with how Zillow's website works? When I go to the above URL in my browser it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

Try to modify one line in your code:

```
zillowURL <- paste0("http://www.zillow.com/", searchTerms[j], "/home-values/", sep="")
```

Then the error message should not occur. The entire URL is required, including the "http://" at the beginning, which web browsers take for granted.